# Mysql dump from cloudbees

Tags: cloudbees

I would like to download MySQL snapshots from cloudbees but it does not seem to be possible. How do you do dump for your dev or debug from cloudbees ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to connect to the database directly from your development workstation using the settings shown in the RUN@cloud console.

Thus you are able to use a local mysqldump or similar to extract the data you need.

See the following pages for more information:

- [Database Guide](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseGuide#HConnectingtothedatabasewithaMySQLclient)
- [Database Export](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DatabaseExport)